# Page numbering style changes for page which contains table of contents?

Tags: table-of-contents, header-footer, page-numbering

I am getting this weird problem where the page numbering on the page with my table of contents is of a different style than every other page in my document. Everything compiles fine, no errors, but page number on the table of contents page is just "2", while the rest of the pages are like "1 of 12", "3 of 12", etc.

Can someone explain to me why this is happening and how to fix it? Thanks.

To be clear, the page numbers INSIDE the TOC are fine, it's the page number styling ON THE PAGE WHICH CONTAINS the TOC that is problematic.

EDIT: document class accessible here I believe: 
https://github.com/fuentesdt/tao-1.10.1-p3/blob/master/docs/tex/mao/aiaa-tc.cls

```
\documentclass[]{aiaa-tc}

\title{MAE 161C Class Project: \\ V.A.S.E. \\ 
Venus Atmospheric Sample Return}

\author{\vspace{5cm} \\ People's names(hidden b/c privacy)}

\usepackage{dcolumn}%   decimal-aligned tabular math columns
\newcolumntype{d}{D{.}{.}{-1}}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks = true, linkcolor  = black}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[titletoc,title]{appendix}
\usepackage{tocloft} %http://ctan.org/pkg/tocloft
\setlength{\cftsecnumwidth}{3em}
\setlength{\cftsubsecnumwidth}{3em}
\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing

\begin{document}


\maketitle
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage


\section{Executive Summary}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\newpage


\tableofcontents
\newpage


\section{List of Figures}
\newpage
...
```

Comment: Is the document class `aiaa-tc.cls` accessible publicly? Where?

Comment: https://github.com/fuentesdt/tao-1.10.1-p3/blob/master/docs/tex/mao/aiaa-tc.cls

I've had to use it for school, sorry if it's obscure. Does this help?

Comment: Try adding `\makeatletter \let\ps@plain\ps@fancy \makeatother` to your preamble (just before `\begin{document}`).

Answer (score 1):

The document class doesn't change anything in terms of the style for `\tableofcontents`. By default, classes load the `plain` page style for the first pages of major document elements, so you could probably get by with making `plain` the same as `fancy`, adding

```
\makeatletter
\let\ps@plain\ps@fancy % Copy fancy page style into/over plain
\makeatother
```

to your preamble.